# Angular-cli RC 5 Adding multiple components to app.module.ts

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-components, angular-rc5

In my Angular-cli RC5 project I am trying to create charts.

1. Created a new component as "chart"
2. Created a directive as "line-graph.directive.ts"

Folder structure.

[image]

app.module.ts

```
import {NgModule, enableProdMode}       from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {AppComponent}   from './app.component';
import {ChartComponent} from './chart/chart.component';
import {LineGraphDirective} from './chart/line-graph.directive';

@NgModule({
   declarations: [AppComponent, ChartComponent, LineGraphDirective],
   providers: [],
   imports: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

chart.component.html

```
<p>
 chart works!
</p>
```

Then, I added following inside the app.component.html as below.

```
<app-chart></app-chart>
```

Then "chart works!" line should display when I run the application.

But it doesn't.

**chart.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
 moduleId: module.id,
 selector: 'app-chart',
 templateUrl: 'chart.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['chart.component.css'],
 directives: []
})
export class ChartComponent {
  constructor() {}
}
```

**line-graph.directive.ts**

```
import {Directive, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: 'line-graph'
})

export class LineGraphDirective {
  constructor() {}
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';
}
```

Any suggestions of what i have done wrong with my code.

Thank You

Comment: what you are getting as output ? are you getting any error ?

Comment: There's no any error. The page shows only the html content of app.component.html file.

Comment: From your folder structure your both  chart component import path looks confusing. whats the code of `ChartComponent` and `LineGraphDirective`?

Comment: @ranakrunal9, I have posted the code for ChartComponent and LineGraphDirective. chart directory & app.module.ts are inside the app folder and line-graph-directive.ts file is inside the chart directory.

Comment: post your `app.component.ts` code

Comment: @pdfarhad, I have posted app.component.ts code

Comment: This is it? You didnt import chart.component in your app.component.ts

Comment: But I imported ChartComponent in AppModule

Answer (score 1):

If you look in your browser's network requests, I bet you will find some `404 not found` errors when `Angular` tries to load the chart component.

Your import paths are not correct.  Change

```
import {ChartComponent} from './chart/chart.component';
import {LineGraphDirective} from './chart/line-graph.directive';
```

With the right paths.  The folder structure is difficult for me to make out from your image (small indentation) but your current import would only work if the `chart` directory was in the same folder as `AppModule`

Comment: There's no any 404 not found error. chart directory and app.module are inside app folder

Comment: @Rose18 ok. The structure is tough for me to see.  If you inline the template (put it in `template: '<p>Chart works!</p>` instead of using `templateUrl`), does it work?

Comment: I tried by adding inline template to ChartComponent, it doesn't work either :(

Answer (score 0):

You also have to import your chart component in the app.component.ts .
Just add

```
import {ChartComponent} from './chart/chart.component';
```

It will definitely work

Answer (score 0):

You need to also declare your Component at the bootstrap metadata in the `app.module.ts`.
Without it, it won't display the content of your Component. 
I have also encountered this problem just a few hours ago.

So your `app.module.ts` should look like this:

```
import {NgModule, enableProdMode}       from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {AppComponent}   from './app.component';
import {ChartComponent} from './chart/chart.component';
import {LineGraphDirective} from './chart/line-graph.directive';

@NgModule({
   declarations: [AppComponent, ChartComponent, LineGraphDirective],
   providers: [],
   imports: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent,ChartComponent],
})
export class AppModule {
}
```